# Search apps based on intent filter

Tags: android, google-play, text-to-speech

I'd like to make my user find new TTS engines, that is: apps which define the following intent filter.

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.TTS_SERVICE" />
</intent-filter>
```

I see on StackOverflow some people making an intent with a URI structured like `market://search?q=pname:[package]`, to search for a specific package name. I can't find a comprehensive definition of the `market://` protocol. Maybe it is possible like this? Or maybe another way?